# Unable to decrypt EFS files after changing user credentials in Win 10

Tags: windows-10, encryption, efs, certutil

I had encrypted some files and folders in my local user account in Windows 10.
I changed the username and password of that local user account and also the administrator account.
After that, I was unable to open or decrypt those encrypted files.
I had saved one `.pfx` file but couldn't install it.
But the reason I couldn't install this certificate file is, I had encrypted this too.

I used `certmgr` and tried to export but I was unable to do so.
I also used `certutil` to repair but I got error.

I contacted Microsoft Support but they did the same like I tried before.
After long inspection, they said they couldn't help.

I searched online and found a third-party software (mimikatz) to solve this problem.
But I got stuck when I didn't find the SHA1 hash of my local user account.
It said SHA1 hash is not present in SAM file of c:\windows\system32\config.
I didn't know where to look then.

I wonder if anybody could help me in this case.

Comment: Did you change the password or reset the password?  If you reset your password to the account and you had encrypted files, then those files are gone forever. Anyone that says otherwise, that your files are gone if you reset the password, is not telling you the truth.  If you changed your password, then you should have been able to import the certificate, but if that certificate was stored in the folder that was encrypted, then you might have to accept your files cannot be recovered. What error did you receive?  [Edit] your question to include that exact (English) error you received

Comment: I changed the password.
I don't know about resetting the password.
The backup certificate (.pfx) file is inside the encrypted folder so I cannot install it.
I also don't remember the username and password of that user account.

Comment: Did you use the "Change Password" option or did you use an Administrator account to change the password to the account?  Changing your password shouldn't have caused the lost of access to your encrypted files while resetting your password would invalidate even a certificate that was installed. Regardless, if your unable to install the certificate, the files are gone because they are encrypted.

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I changed the password of both local and admin account at the same time.
I just used EFSdump.exe and it shows the username of the deleted local account.
But one thing, why in the certificate, it says that "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate".

Comment: Because you’re supposed to have one. You could attempt to go through the motions to determine if you reset password or changed your password, did you use the user management tool, or go through the secure desktop and hit “change password”, regardless of which method, the certificate cannot be used since it’s clearly not installed and the backup of the certificate you have is encrypted

Comment: I changed the password in control panel's user accounts and changed the password and username.
I have one laptop where I had used that certificate once.
But when I see the certificate information using certmgr.msc, it says, "This CA Root certificate is not trusted. To enable trust, install this certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store."
It also says, "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate."
Is there any way I can use this certificate from this laptop to decrypt the encrypted files in my PC.

Comment: Has the certificate expired?

Comment: In both laptop and PC, no. The certificate is valid from 12/22/2022 to 11/28/2122.
I also have the username (using EFSdump.exe) and I think I remember the password now (it's similar to my current password) in my PC.
Is there any chance I can get help?

Comment: If it’s encrypted, no, it still can’t be used because it’s not installed.

Comment: But what about the certificate in my laptop?
I mean the (.pfx) file is encrypted in my PC.
But in my laptop, I had there are no encrypted files.
Isn't there anything I could do to decrypt the files?